# access outer variable that has changed after its first creation

Tags: javascript, function

I know I can access outer variable in function object but, here is what I'm stuck with.

```
zero = function (one) {
    this.one = one;
    this.two = {
        three: {
            four: function() {
                one.test();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the dirty code naming :(. 
But here's the test case.

```
foo = {
    test: function() {
        console.log('foo test');
    }
}
bar = new zero(foo);
bar.two.three.four(); // prints 'foo test'
foo2 = {
    test: function() {
        console.log('another foo test');
    }
};
bar.one = foo2;
bar.two.three.four(); // still prints 'foo test' instead of 'another foo test'
```

It looks like `four` keeps the reference of `one` since its creation not the reference of variable in `bar`. And I cannot figure out how I can directly access to the outer variable. Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
var zero = function (one) {
    var _this = this;
    this.one = one;
    this.two = {
        three: {
            four: function () {
                _this.one.test();
            }
        }
    };
};
```

instead of

```
one.test();
```

That uses the closure variable instead of the publicly visible instance property.

When you do this:

```
this.one = foo2;
```

What you're actually doing is overwriting the publicly visible property. However, this is distinct from the argument to your function called `one`, which is within the scope of your function created. `one` is never changed in your code, therefore it's only natural that you're getting the valve from the initial assignment in your constructor function. Assigning a property to an object does not mean that they will be the same. If you do this inside a constructor:

```
function Test()
{   var test = {};
    this.test = test;
    test = { a: 1 };
    console.log(this.test.a);
}

new Test; // undefined is logged
```

The reason why `_this` is used in the new function is that the value of `this` is only set when the function is called, not when it is defined. For example, take this behaviour:

```
function Example()
{   var _this = this;
    this.test1 = { func: function () { return this; }
    this.test2 = { func: function () { return _this; }
}

var instance = new Example;
var randomFunction1 = instance.test1.func;
var randomFunction2 = instance.test2.func;

instance.test1.func(); // the instance.test1 object
instance.test2.func(); // the actual instance

randomFunction1(); // the global object (though this will be undefined in strict mode)
randomFunction2(); // still the instance
```

The first is the way it is because the parent object of the method is `instance.test1`, not `instance`. By assigning the object reference *at that time* to a variable, we can permanently store this reference and refer to it any time that you like.

Note: you might want to use `var` to declare your variable - this prevents implied globals which can be particularly nasty, and also assignments to undeclared variables are not permitted in strict mode.

Comment: Thanks for the awesomely fast answer. I understood what the problem was. And thanks for the tip as well. Just one thing, I've seen people using `_this` in their code, is this some kind of coding pattern in JS? I also noticed sometimes they use double underscores.

Comment: Wow I see it now. with `_this` you still can keep the track of reference to its parent object not the function itself. This looks like a cool pattern I will keep using. Thanks heaps Qantas tho I like JetStar better...

Comment: @EugeneYu: well not the function, but the object that the method is a direct property of (and called from).